# Azure load balancing rule based on source network

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Is it possible with the Azure load balancer to create a load balancing rule based on source network? For example:

Connections from 10.1.0.0/16 to port 9000 go to backend port 9100

Connections from 10.2.0.0/16 to port 9000 go to backend port 9200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible because the frontend IP configuration only includes the IP address, protocol, and port. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-standard-manage-portal#create-a-load-balancer-rule). Also, if you intend to configure an internal LB, then frontends and backends should be inside a virtual network.

> A Load Balancer rule is used to define how traffic is distributed to
>   the VMs. You define the frontend IP configuration for the incoming
>   traffic and the backend IP pool to receive the traffic, along with the
>   required source and destination port.

and

> The frontend (aka VIP) is defined by a 3-tuple comprised of an IP
>   address (public or internal), a transport protocol (UDP or TCP), and a
>   port number from the load balancing rule.

For more information, you could read [multiple frontends for Azure Load Balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-multivip-overview).